# Sklearn SVM makes incorrect boundary line on a clearly linearly seperable dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm currently working on my thesis about fault detection using SVM. So I used kernel fisher discriminant analysis to extract 52 features of my dataset into plot-able 2 features and then I used SVM to classify the data. I used this algorithm before to classify my dataset into 5 classes, and now I want to classify them into just 2 classes (normal vs faulty).

The training set is used to get the KPCA transformation matrix (KPCA_mat), the FDA transformation matrix (FDA_mat), and the SVM. The testing set must be processed using kernel, KPCA_mat, and FDA_mat before classified using SVM. I hope that explains the background well enough.

So after I use KFDA on my training set, I plot them like so:

```
#Training
#dummy function: y1_train = KFDA(X_train)

from sklearn import svm
clf= svm.SVC()
clf = clf.fit(y1_train.T,L) #y1_train is my training set after KFDA, and L is it's labels
colorcode = ['red', 'green']

y1_train = np.array(y1_train.T)
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(L)):
    plt.scatter(y_train[L == j, 0], y_train[L == j, 1],
                c = colorcode[i], label = j)
plt.title('Classification(Training Set)')
plt.xlabel('LD1')
plt.ylabel('LD2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which results in one clearly linearly separable data-plot:
[training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxH8g.png)

after, I run KFDA on my testing set and then plot them, like so:

```
K_test = rbf_kernel(X_train,X_test)
#I used KFDA proposed here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0031320303004205
#Where KFDA = KPCA + FDA

y_test = KPCA_mat.T.dot(K_test) #U is my KPCA transofrmation matrix
y1_test = FDA_mat.T.dot(y_test) #U1 is my FDA transofrmation matrix

y1_test = pd.DataFrame.from_records(y1_test)
y1_pred = clf.predict(y1_test.T)

y1_test = np.array(y1_test.T)
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y1_test)):
    plt.scatter(y1_test[y1_pred == j, 0], y1_test[y1_pred == j, 1],
                c = colorcode[i],label = j)
plt.title('Classification(Testing Set)')
plt.xlabel('LD1')
plt.ylabel('LD2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

the result was really unexpected and frustrating, it only predicts the dataset into just 1 class:
[testing set classified by SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiOgj.png)

If I use linear discriminant analysis instead, I get this satisfying result of:
[testing set classified by LDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWmI2.png)

Oh yes, and when I tried to use fewer samples, I have these results for the training set:
[training set plot with fewer samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j5BJ.png)
and the SVM classified result the same training set:
[fewer samples training set classified by SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfzEg.png)

SVM clearly decided to make **2 horizontal boundary lines** instead of 1 vertical boundary line and I have no idea how it came to be.

To perhaps narrow your incoming solutions, the code works wonderfully on the same dataset but with 5 classes. Both with 5 classes or 2 classes, the labels are integer.
So far I haven't got any luck on fixing this, any help or advice? Thanks a lot!

Here's a part of my dataset and it's labels. You may want to train your SVM with this and then use the SVM to classify the dataset. You should see the same results I have below:
[Training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s83wp.png)
[Training set classified using SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYkjv.png)

```
0,1,Labels
3.553228913,2919244.025,1
3.223378877,3698228.57,1
3.716576738,28276799.91,1
3.818688029,38432349.38,1
3.334108342,-3340107.004,1
2.42317704,856944.0099,1
3.823220789,38600119.14,1
3.49646761,21942327.79,1
3.380999482,30350085.98,1
3.609854132,6101423.329,1
3.787058988,18513524.28,1
3.065980083,-12382454.97,1
3.496160098,15526495.87,1
2.840583547,27446699.86,1
3.604069836,20067620.19,1
3.071505165,11795892.91,1
3.209584714,6476417.198,1
2.97205153,29557710.6,1
2.899374677,19817430.73,1
3.669208033,15644387.19,1
3.068740276,1260284.263,1
3.063901217,-7497534.523,1
3.31799035,14945441.54,1
3.183425793,29100856.96,1
2.774634674,1122485.168,1
2.707394236,-13468805.33,1
3.517935754,33678125.03,1
3.68810298,23299531.68,1
3.020844304,8969026.657,1
2.359208637,-14122618.74,1
2.588698876,43134990.75,1
2.779307816,39889831.76,1
2.991716289,-12841577.67,1
2.697619578,-4612248.957,1
3.823644915,15792133.64,1
3.744496817,15334030.83,1
3.444225142,17547178.47,1
3.139323032,18080654.5,1
3.332970955,9982626.927,1
3.101179668,14143713.04,1
3.185501617,23381531.99,1
3.368897517,29883832.88,1
3.77536243,29349931,1
3.950664228,25932025.14,1
3.40945779,-19417445.1,1
3.684768515,22368278.8,1
3.949967013,2300505.867,1
3.735718563,1973558.229,1
3.389415162,30424323.86,1
3.744275962,35375791.02,1
3.681084285,10460466.17,1
4.080701669,21381145.33,1
4.0032667,12268602.92,1
3.58398002,2322964.316,1
3.741034387,17075904.36,1
4.201503247,11302866.78,1
3.533658048,52826863.96,1
3.806515585,44111366.42,1
3.902127707,39719296.27,1
3.812873792,29406769.6,1
3.821779054,17044960.31,1
3.741950398,13712669.85,1
2.985308648,14274473.39,1
3.29148911,10071888.63,1
3.482015336,37636918.4,1
3.23356351,45595555.91,1
3.416125942,41920805.21,1
3.940062703,62679318.7,1
4.200859937,55601099.73,1
4.051566173,34334380.19,1
3.193366685,17470226.02,1
2.536406579,18936263.48,1
3.435668864,19078047.58,1
3.159829877,15046920.65,1
3.269595835,19771786.52,1
3.197403747,24016660.3,1
3.878417918,39048455.59,1
2.938778993,31167462.71,1
3.469616826,27280447.88,1
2.910497205,10878193.53,1
3.069773059,32272369.02,1
2.603927406,3827262.997,1
2.615230098,-23734492.39,1
2.907962877,-7393308.522,1
3.327754319,14997163.66,1
3.452463322,10357657.97,1
3.083577372,-15573490.26,1
3.210440204,-23628723.36,1
2.898827183,10479620.42,1
3.054028869,-8520274.966,1
2.881773778,2132237.861,1
3.014938358,8796615.989,1
3.270746874,8827848.137,1
3.256951059,28060704.32,1
3.054982642,-13593440.76,1
2.732409906,-14489554.31,1
3.332972378,-16313231.12,1
3.050729307,-15427087.55,1
2.982385741,1071818.662,1
3.102925917,-26552171.47,1
3.741136781,4412226.733,1
3.749396343,-2705194.787,1
3.448637233,13416279.17,1
3.521931468,2587776.003,1
3.946611418,8013361.468,1
3.020131352,13015831.52,1
3.58829354,27992234.8,1
2.955616396,11764853.2,1
3.254278877,17490728.72,1
3.030120454,-7945033.333,1
3.497027423,17901939.44,1
3.68007556,22596729.7,1
3.549762534,11181336.29,1
3.521980034,-11285958.12,1
3.03631875,24019024.35,1
4.007915614,24641675.61,1
3.526523693,21195764.76,1
3.748938713,7393049.237,1
4.207147018,41837871.46,1
3.993076596,29103711.31,1
3.511322893,38241966.02,1
3.517900772,12353860.46,1
3.392837002,1394155.365,1
3.406008771,5268054.685,1
3.743510132,20131936.32,1
2.950332123,47448720.29,1
3.839271555,30030531.7,1
3.170647786,47005853.34,1
3.445553471,13780765.06,1
3.571773339,11354675.45,1
3.862347321,43854362.03,1
3.611605696,62556.42001,1
2.870385863,45969108.7,1
3.342068101,37259016.92,1
3.074472072,14515182.46,1
3.485911447,137793.857,1
3.984245047,45454168.12,1
3.824460011,52306602.53,1
3.785593499,3499535.921,1
3.962261738,15088672.92,1
3.039061814,25052648.57,1
3.443241437,30520587.7,1
3.657241878,21506506.85,1
4.072878549,17177802.8,1
3.505283321,13517850.04,1
3.526808794,11741167.25,1
3.591865346,39323590.46,1
3.750272292,15651712.66,1
4.258482956,50940231.5,1
4.087269313,56126135,1
4.386697652,51820965.03,1
3.440454966,23443550.64,1
4.528384928,42705991.77,1
4.099245005,45303259.03,1
4.105317426,43752994.63,1
3.681487891,27623434.77,1
3.687778948,35766583.44,1
3.614605141,14301619.91,1
4.021837027,8997579.769,1
3.344575843,4339300.988,1
3.314377806,-5320081.795,1
3.015562047,-11602826.82,1
2.64203582,8570037.275,1
3.446672972,20673340.05,1
3.467901188,26466476.44,1
3.287902775,21759630.74,1
3.64246169,9542759.914,1
3.319296801,3496745.42,1
3.662688387,48034127.46,1
3.172038427,20233885.76,1
3.701292481,-7619589.126,1
3.424238489,-1402424.608,1
3.156049789,-6103578.039,1
3.219097728,-5710870.258,1
2.765958713,3087825.924,1
2.888227845,13911236.37,1
2.633173877,-12614523.65,1
2.548631215,-30267519.28,1
2.543092202,-26406006.67,1
3.009558586,22785392.46,1
3.080924417,-10755770.1,1
3.737736984,10924558.28,1
3.447619488,10773991.53,1
2.963019275,7689912.223,1
3.153506139,-20594868.09,1
2.878955008,29231170.62,1
3.087086267,12347138.67,1
3.107825104,27729501.17,1
2.891606228,-12039724.88,1
2.803128403,4896812.239,1
3.151139413,-16385802.17,1
2.681273034,-28808725.54,1
2.527343617,-1284679.474,1
2.243411551,-14021320.89,1
2.608116853,-13522626.97,1
2.444513372,4224689.372,1
2.93488514,-25875464.83,1
3.070678547,-14331113.64,1
3.200569604,18448766.11,1
3.041766951,-4796543.743,1
4.001175253,-25760489.11,2
4.418063529,-5805154.42,2
5.115801828,3499631.796,2
5.295685096,-5373603.715,2
4.726248107,-23946431.83,2
4.581869096,-14248729.14,2
5.108444511,4168858.481,2
4.829287584,-1922178.405,2
5.241699069,-3901768.377,2
5.481647228,-24841613.36,2
6.030982291,-10415145.45,2
5.600162275,-1906380.269,2
5.538437592,22738043.31,2
5.768213382,27513657.59,2
5.890889539,4466233.751,2
5.686334333,21072963.1,2
5.371262664,38987533.52,2
5.652396464,5459984.599,2
5.297690911,-5464601.161,2
5.583487473,-1886926.071,2
6.017678097,24117886.1,2
5.854431388,23519831.23,2
5.945624236,12088353.25,2
5.148553726,-22523086.38,2
5.432166886,16753466.03,2
5.462867668,-8347388.408,2
5.798267347,1139410.466,2
6.355480618,10857015.17,2
6.142339581,24345815.51,2
5.97257871,21774060.96,2
4.751841455,-14963907.39,2
5.515585633,-7531373.353,2
5.306212458,34156521.25,2
4.9164911,24185591.17,2
5.493347601,27641575.23,2
5.415264556,38974337.17,2
6.026729962,35420751.78,2
6.081210524,47932048.35,2
6.172041194,19015312.98,2
6.028744892,8921558.636,2
5.302570941,2681291.902,2
5.935657068,14993456.09,2
5.671558452,43762248.48,2
5.980681841,73991988.64,2
5.892808409,31022059.37,2
6.143973404,39005358.28,2
6.597681328,63007772.34,2
5.885757092,52620583.86,2
5.975814018,16670571.69,2
6.482183401,46092335.83,2
5.766015645,38790243.03,2
5.741821036,53576375.39,2
4.879191857,21965094.53,2
5.334212964,29366016.42,2
5.683683265,39798337.08,2
5.850368893,54269323.01,2
6.869270028,44410405.45,2
5.831132777,25017332.88,2
6.65985176,30719621.69,2
6.749542604,59235105.41,2
6.133851547,60864212.07,2
6.142943016,48453185.24,2
6.210843969,52080287.52,2
5.544545164,54280670.08,2
6.425415782,59274649.59,2
5.750703701,35087973.86,2
6.205166878,47169196.57,2
5.638458297,75055698.44,2
5.325977743,20880243.4,2
6.233705249,27255581.73,2
5.405699551,31387107.55,2
6.550842637,42605262.37,2
6.274213959,49355176.91,2
6.390231328,81274307.78,2
5.848394946,39016667.31,2
5.862251592,16947992.44,2
5.700203175,19318199.49,2
6.212682108,37016308.49,2
6.576637468,57602902.24,2
6.827133391,49784352.3,2
6.169729947,49642934.17,2
6.471437049,34733673.16,2
5.728366796,26680700.35,2
5.446699339,3265360.992,2
6.226715031,26275982.39,2
6.159318796,16146291.08,2
6.632247793,16704948.71,2
6.668349394,28573866.83,2
6.690083664,40925466.71,2
7.249452567,27640480.1,2
6.454383887,47491716.78,2
6.974657476,51355293.32,2
6.321454815,42656583.32,2
6.801239108,33256436.13,2
6.627392232,50478459.39,2
6.461820046,61817446.12,2
7.335742137,58062639.93,2
7.398130963,69876511.9,2
6.276486971,52100423.91,2
6.726317308,59562512.4,2
6.851858499,76356310.28,2
7.051028098,67830368.43,2
6.953239001,73447871.7,2
7.621957559,59651706.2,2
6.998873461,69482393.09,2
6.738587142,43734907.26,2
7.25095493,52546354.98,2
7.23864016,58420746.7,2
7.433460411,42721986.58,2
7.418987521,53213337.12,2
6.687302432,50288883.77,2
6.219808308,53569149.34,2
6.470663737,45635102.84,2
7.194048264,34740469.37,2
7.591257536,63146058.09,2
7.454257239,57508286.44,2
6.756688194,42817308.5,2
7.033352097,51149325.92,2
7.256733141,41538162.36,2
7.118063024,49169585.4,2
6.629253239,30978674.73,2
6.529623883,29018247.91,2
6.59264715,59060510.82,2
6.929568607,44737559.3,2
6.48812861,11844005.39,2
6.718177617,16391915.71,2
6.082187587,2846652.97,2
6.298579947,1187703.357,2
6.718219791,27732053.95,2
7.291596104,595617.8814,2
6.82801739,-696288.8684,2
6.79819973,-3262543.561,2
6.623407323,-2180973.673,2
6.602635889,15101538.57,2
6.548826556,9896153.206,2
7.038066751,16975941.22,2
6.868920218,15998317.36,2
6.617009722,9788671.962,2
7.165822981,55318468.2,2
7.515150664,33885385.73,2
7.748503827,20620215.86,2
7.860953326,13819190.26,2
7.165742129,-10750403.6,2
7.264077555,-19463846.9,2
7.961258634,29336350.72,2
7.657262403,22222463.53,2
6.97400566,-15171273.82,2
6.985184463,-11637163.3,2
7.049911622,17699094.48,2
6.71432548,9260422.296,2
7.578722796,-10938918.01,2
7.157337822,-34206775.43,2
7.63790338,1618780.768,2
6.947144555,19760236.37,2
7.259060257,-25354442.71,2
6.201018793,-32562663.55,2
6.615037561,-9655821.914,2
6.699685448,-18958614.87,2
5.734442646,-31906331.8,2
6.321051159,-52127193.24,2
7.280449431,-11048866.54,2
6.891618144,-8803551.629,2
6.989631564,-26996948.81,2
7.808043663,-18291620.68,2
7.417919826,-31054317.66,2
7.372159728,-29648226.32,2
7.626852989,-15082445.76,2
7.349335689,-34424689.98,2
6.965648468,-43340181.24,2
7.117652687,-29890963.59,2
6.347651466,2290407.857,2
6.482477024,-32935282.16,2
6.900529229,-21373007.13,2
7.14510909,-10669731.44,2
6.949514541,-36703352.77,2
6.216513334,-32401759.18,2
7.006058886,-21032879.44,2
6.433040652,-46740948.53,2
6.646303229,-36762306.73,2
7.015561634,-19897470.69,2
6.428254672,-60896684.46,2
6.292196932,-47398508.74,2
6.744765768,-35987789.98,2
6.940687641,-30481109,2
6.595533187,-40183549.15,2
6.252549613,-29561422.85,2
6.310925413,-36229646.32,2
6.320073308,-31423542.15,2
6.930051571,-36856614.72,2
6.290121879,-22000253.63,2
6.824774069,-52437163.74,2
6.40359095,-37324956.6,2
6.874800798,-28716175.07,2
6.494900205,-17523000.17,2
6.385512661,-32704461.99,2
6.653061033,-48644014.51,2
5.943817589,-33455610.16,2
5.921086039,-26486444.68,2
6.077362467,-24486331.52,2
5.634420068,-64633618.75,2
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code for this issue? In your code its not clear where and how you are using the SVM. I assume the "clf" is your svm? Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm really sorry about that. I already edited the post for this.
Yes, "clf" is indeed my SVM, and it's truly just as simple as clf = svm(). Which leads to me not knowing where to start to fix the code :(

Comment: Thanks for updating it, but for instance 'y1_train' is still undefined, which means your code can not be run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda stuck between this thought. The problem is that the commented dummy KFDA function is, well kinda long. So I hesitate to put it all down here. The underlined statement is, the KFDA function + SVM works on the same dataset but with 5 classes, and linear discriminant analysis is able to classify the 2 class dataset quote-unquote "correctly", or rather, "intuitively".
Having to know this, do you perhaps have any ideas on how SVM could've decided to make the aforementioned horizontal boundary instead of a vertical boundary?

Comment: Try to simply create a dummy data from your data, which you can provide here so that your problem can be reproduced with your code. Otherwise without reproducible code, it is difficult to help you here.

Comment: Whoa, Thank you! I didn't think of that. I really appreciate your efforts in helping me out! So yeah, I uploaded a snippet that is actually a part of my dataset. You would want to train the SVM with it, and then use the SVM to classify the data itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how I can use your data. If i try to put brackets around it to use it as a dataframe for pandas or a list, the commas at the end of each line are missing.

Comment: I would recommend to import them as CSV. It actually is a csv file but i copied them and put it in a snippet. So you can copy them to your notepad and then import them into excel using the "from text" method. This does sound kinda roundabout, is there anything I can do to make it easier? I'll try to reformat them so you can copy it in the morning. Or is there any direct method?

Comment: Okay thank you, I managed to load your data and got a similar result (but not the same) as yours from the first snippet. But now for the second snippet, "X_train" and "X_test" are undefined. Can you provide that, or dummy data of that kind?

Comment: Hold on, you got a similar result as my first snippet? 
I need to straighten this out so we could have the same understanding. The result should be the exact same as the 2 results I showed in the last paragraf, one for plotting the dataset, and one for plotting the classification results. I got those results by fitting the SVM using the dataset and then using the SVM to classify the same dataset.

Provided this, you should have no need for X_train and X_test to reproduce the problem. Thanks!